# FxCop - can it be told to ignore LINQ to SQL classes?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, fxcop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exclude complete namespace from FxCop code analysis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353110/exclude-complete-namespace-from-fxcop-code-analysis)

I'm running FxCop as a post-build step of my class library project and it's picking up violations from the LINQ-to-SQL generated code.

I am running FxCop as follows (line breaks added for clarity):

```
<PostBuildEvent>
  "$(SystemDrive)\Utils\DeveloperTools\fxcop\FxCopCmd.exe"
  /file:"$(TargetPath)" /console
  /out:"$(ProjectDir)obj\$(ConfigurationName)\FxCopResults.xml" /q
</PostBuildEvent>
```

My LINQ classes are in a dedicated namespace, `Data`, as in:

```
Data\MainDataContext.dbml
Data\MainDataContext.dbml.layout
Data\MainDataContact.designer.cs
```

#### Question

Is there any way to reliably tell FxCop *not* to check these files?