# In Visual Studio 2013 how do I limit code analysis to my code and not to referenced assemblies?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, code-analysis, ilmerge

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2013 (c# code) that has a reference to a third-party assembly that I added with NuGet (ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib).  When I run the "Code Analysis" on the solution I get lots of warnings coming from the third-party assembly.  How do I tell VS that I only want code analysis advice from my code?

I'm pretty sure the errors are coming from the library itself and not my usage of it. There are a total of 32 issues e.g.

> CA2237: Mark ISerializable types with SerializableAttribute.

I am using ILMerge to bundle into a single executable do you think that has confused the code analysis?

Comment: @jessehouwing I'm pretty sure it is the library itself.  There are a total of 32 issues e.g. "CA2237: Mark ISerializable types with SerializableAttribute".  I am using ILMerge to bundle into a single .exe do you think that has confused the code analysis? Thanks for the style fix to the post BTW.

Comment: While you're getting used to StackOverflow, my next tip is to edit your question when new information is asked or useful, like in this case your comment on IlMerge. It's easier to follow for others when they read the question afresh in the future. http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Comment: You want to run Code Analysis only on your Debug configuration.  There is no point in using ILMerge in that configuration, you only care about it in the Release build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to tell FxCop to ignore namespaces or types in your code if it lives in the same binaries. When using ILMerge, the SharpZipLib essentially becomes part of your code, as it's merged into your assembly.

To get proper results, run FxCop on the assembly that's generated before the merge.

Other [solutions will mention to put a `[GeneratedCode]` attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/353110/exclude-complete-namespace-from-fxcop-code-analysis) on classes you want excluded, but IlMerge has no option to to that while merging, so that won't help you out.

In Visual Studio 2015 Code Analysis works on the source code using the new Roslyn Engine, which will solve the issue probably, as it does the analysis even before compilation and as such will not be impacted by your use of IlMerge.